# Apply modifier to Image like in AsyncImage

Tags: swift, swiftui

my goal is to have a custom AsyncImage View because I need to authenticate my request.
Therefore I have created a custom struct which implements this. Now my only problem is that I want to add modifiers to my loaded Image.

Something like this:

```
CustomAsyncImageView(dataKey: dataKey) { image in    
     image
        .resizable()                
} placeholder: {
     Rectangle()
}
```

What I tried:

```
struct CustomAsyncImageView<Content> : View where Content : View {
    
    var content: Content
    
    var image: Image?
    
    // I left out the Image loading
    
    public init<I, P>(dataKey: String, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Image) -> I, @ViewBuilder placeholder: @escaping () -> P)  {
        // I have this init from AsyncImage, but I have no idea how to initialize my properties
    }

    var body: some View {
        if let image = image {
            image
        } else {
            // show placeholder
        }
    }
}
```

Is this type of initialization possible to implement or should I pass the viewModifier as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not too far off. You would have to store the `content` closure, as well as the `placeholder` closure, and execute them in your `body`.

I also don't believe you need the `@ViewBuilder` attribute.

```
struct CustomAsyncImageView<I, P>: View where I: View, P: View {
    let content: (Image) -> I
    let placeholder: () -> P
    var image: Image?
    
    public init(dataKey: String, content: @escaping (Image) -> I, placeholder: @escaping () -> P)  {
        self.content = content
        self.placeholder = placeholder
    }

    var body: some View {
        if let image = image {
            content(image)
        } else {
            placeholder()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without the "<I, P>" after the init it works. Thank your very much!

Comment: @Nero yes that would create another generic types with no relation with the structure ones.